# Error width 100% al cargarse la tabla con la libreria CanvasJS

Tags: jquery, html, css

tengo un problema al utilizar la libreria CanvasJS. Defino el siguiente div:

```
<div id="resizable" style="height: 300px;">
    <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Y añado este script el antes de cerrar el body:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Better to construct options first and then pass it as a parameter
    var options1 = {
        title: {
            text: "Chart inside a jQuery Resizable Element"
        },
                animationEnabled: true,
        data: [
        {
        type: "column", //change it to line, area, bar, pie, etc
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 10 },
                { y: 6 },
                { y: 14 },
                { y: 12 },
                { y: 19 },
                { y: 14 },
                { y: 26 },
                { y: 10 },
                { y: 22 }
            ]
        }
        ]
    };

    $("#resizable").resizable({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            //Create chart.
            $("#chartContainer1").CanvasJSChart(options1);
        },
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            //Update chart size according to its container's size.
            $("#chartContainer1").CanvasJSChart().render();
        }
    });

});
```

Esta como en el ejemplo que viene en la documentación, solo he cambiado

```
window.onload = function () {
```

Por esto:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Pero a la hora de cargar la página, no me aparece al 100% de ancho, sino solo un 30% mas o menos, pero si reduzco el tamaño de la ventana y la agrando, si se coloca con ancho al 100%. Alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema? Gracias!

El contenido html importante seria asi:

Css del head

```
<link href="path_to_folder/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Inicio del body

```
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div id="resizable" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
              <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

El footer seria asi

```
<script src="path_to_folder/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_folder/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_folder/js/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

Y debajo de esto va el script que he añadido arriba

Comment: Porqué te es necesario cambiar el `window.onload` ? Si es 100% necesario mírate este link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872620/canvasjs-graphs-skewed-until-zoom-level-changed

Comment: Lo cambie, por si se estaba ahi el error, pero de las dos formas sigue sin cargar con el ancho al 100%

Comment: y SI cambias el width del div `resizable` de 300px a 100%?

Comment: Lo acabo de añadir pero sigue saliendo solo al 30% de ancho mas o menos

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema ([jsFiddle con tu código funcionando sin incidentes](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm9a01po/)). ¿Podrías compartir el contenido relevante de tu HTML para mostrar el error? (crear un fragmento JavaScript/HTML en la misma pregunta haciendo Ctrl+M)

Comment: Ya he añadido el contenido, si no es suficiente añado mas

Comment: Creo que el problema está en `<div class="col-md-12">` --> Puedes quitarlo temporalmente (y puedes poiner width 100% a TODOS los divs? Sólo para comprobar.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, solo se cambia al 100% si reduzco la ventana

Comment: prueba de hacer un `$("#chartContainer1").CanvasJSChart().render();` en el `windows.onload`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, pero gracias de todas formas

Comment: Hay algun error en consola? (F12)

Comment: No, no da error, la consola esta vacia

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41249/discussion-between-miquel-coll-and-alberto-mier).

Comment: @AlbertoMier te aconsejo crear un jsfiddle para reproducir el problema, es muy probable que en el proceso encuentres el causante error. a medida que vas agregando mas elementos al fiddle, si no es el caso, hay saludos.

Answer (score 0):

¿El div **#resizable** esta dentro de otro div?

Sin saber la respuesta, intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
<div id="resizable" style="height:300px; width:100% !important;">
```